# Create a file based on conditions

Tags: java, file, exception

How to write a program in Java to check the existence of a txt file if does not exist than create a new one else append the new txt in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("foo.txt",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("foo bar");
out.close();
```

The second argumnet to `FileWriter` tells it to append.

Comment: @subodh any reason you don't accept it as the answer than?  Cheers

Comment: i accepted it but it gives me a msg accept it after 5 mins,now i accept..Cheers